# How to call Function within StoredProcedure in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I created one function
select * from f_get_employees1();

I want to call this function in stored procedure .

Comment: And what do you want to do with the result of that function inside your procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to call a function into procedure.You don't need to do this. Even then I give some reference, so you can understand what you want.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dbo.spForCustomerINfo(
    p_name character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    p_mobile character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    p_email character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    p_password character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    p_dob timestamp(3))
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$ 
Declare p_CurrentAge varchar(20);
begin
                    -- Get User Current Age                             
                     Select dbo.fnGetCurrentAgeOfuser(p_dob) into p_CurrentAge;
                    
                    ----- Insert User Data
                    insert into dbo.Customer(name,mobile,email,password,DOB,CurrentAge)
                    values(p_name,p_mobile,p_email,p_password,p_dob,p_CurrentAge);
                 
    commit;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: No need to call function into Proc.

Comment: I know but @pooja need to implement so that's why i provide

Comment: The function call can also be written as: `p_CurrentAge := dbo.fnGetCurrentAgeOfuser(p_dob);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name definitely sir